# Accessing Google APIs after react-redux-firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, google-api, react-redux

I'm using `react-redux-firebase` for authentication via Google which works fine and I can view my user profile within my components render method via the redux store but I can't seem to access a Google access token to use in my action creators for accessing Google's API's.

What's the standard way to grab the access token? `getFirebase()` seems logical but I can't find any mention of a token there.